# Scala lambda in function args

Tags: scala, lambda

I have some code block like this:

```
object EntryPoint extends App {

  val arr = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
  doFirst(arr)

  def doFirst(a: ArrayBuffer[Int]) = {
    doSecond(s"$a")
  }

  def doSecond(
                 x: => String = ""
                 ) = {
    x match {
      case s: String => println(s"This is string: $s")
      case _ => println(x.getClass.getName)
    }
  }
}
```

Output: `This is string: ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)`

Why `x` evaluated like a string if in debugger i see lambda with 3 arguments?
Is it because every call `x` is `x.apply()` ?

Comment: What did you expect? as soon as you reach `x` in your doSecond method, x is evaluated, and you're passing the toString representation of your ArrayBuffer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you see in debugger? Likely in the debugger you see some internal runtime representation of the by-name parameter.

Comment: @GaëlJ in debugger i saw `EntryPoint$$Lambda` with internal field `arg`. I'm interesting in possibility to get that `arg` value manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A by-name parameter like `x: => String`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) is conceptually the same as a function with signature `() => String`

The following are equivalent and as you noticed already **both parameters end up with the same runtime representation when debugging**.

```scala
def doWithByNameParam(x: => String): String =
    x

def doWithFunction(x: () => String): String =
    x.apply()

doWithByNameParam("string")
doWithFunction(() => "string")
```

You just avoid some boilerplate with `doWithByNameParam`

**Later Edit:**

Here's what `javap` will give just so you understand what happens under the hood

```scala
  public static java.lang.String doWithByNameParam(scala.Function0<java.lang.String>);
  public static java.lang.String doWithFunction(scala.Function0<java.lang.String>);
```

Comment: They're not the same, `() => String` is a function from Unit to String! `: => String` does not have an apply method with this signature: `def apply(): String`.

Comment: @AminMal check my response again. I've added a bit more context to my statement.

Comment: I see, but they're not equivalent to each other, at least in compile time. Try this, define `val lazyFunc: () => String = () => "string"`, now if you pass this to `doWithByNameParam`, you'll get compile-time error, since the compiler expects a `String`, while you're passing a function0 of string. And also, you can pass a calculated String to `doWithByNameParam`, while you can't pass the calculated String to the other one obvoiusly! You can use lazy val's for the first one, you can't do it for the second one, and many other minor differences! just like how lazy values and functions differ.

Comment: Yes different types but I mentioned the differences in usage while obtaining the same behaviour.
You can use lazy vals with both approaches without triggering its evaluation:

```lazy val x = ???;  doWithFunction(() => x)```

As i was saying you avoid some boilerplate.

Comment: You’re not calling it just as it is, you’re creating a function from it in your comment’s code sample, that’s what I say, please pay attention to my earlier comment

Comment: The last thing I'll say: for a beginner in my experience it's useful to see by-name params as `Function0`.